# Nested Individual-time conditions on panel data in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data.table, longitudinal

So I have a large data set of students at a school that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
school <- data.table("id" = rep(1:10, each = 10), "year" = rep(2000:2009, each = 10),
 "grade" = sample(c(9:11, rep(NA, 5)), 100, replace = T))
```

What I want to do is create a column that indicates if a student has previously been in the same grade as he is now.

The desired output for this example can be found [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dc90cb7eb5c5b507aa2d33e84339baa920200613021326/236dc8) (I crated a link to save space).

This may sound simple but it is not since students can go back in grades, or be absent in years prior.
I would like a way to do this using `data.table` as the dataset is very large. so far I've tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
school[, repetition := any(school[censor((.I - 10):(.I + 10),
                                         range = c(0, NROW(school))) %>% na.omit
       ][school[.I, id] == id] == grade)]
```

However, this doesn't work as I don't know how to distinguish "upper level" (from the first `school[...]` call) operators like `.I` and `id` from inside the second `school[...]` call.

P.D.: I'll accept suggestions for a better title. Thanks!

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to generate dataset and also show expected output for the given example.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: There is no expected output in your question. You can share it for couple of id's

Comment: It must have taken a moment to update, I created a download link with the desired output to save space. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to get logical value for grades that repeat for each `id` and `year`.

```
library(data.table)
school[, repetition := duplicated(grade, incomparables = NA), .(id, year)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a solution to what I asked and I hence I have marked it as a correct answer. However, I was looking for a more general solution that would allow me to have more flexibility over the data. In particular, I want to be able to have a vector of all the past and future grade the student has seen for every year, that's why I asked for nested conditions. I'll try to be more accurate in my next post.

Comment: Probably you can ask it as a new question.